# Setting background color messes up drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

So I made a custom UIView where I can draw lines based on stuff that is happening in the game, and it all seemed to be working properly (each time drawRect: is called, it **appends** a stroke onto the view)

```
//Initialization
DrawView* draw = [[DrawView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


//And the drawRect method:
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   CGColorRef r = [self.lineColor CGColor];

   CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, CGColorGetComponents(r));
   CGContextBeginPath(c);
   CGContextMoveToPoint(c, self.start.x, self.start.y);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, self.finish.x, self.finish.y);
   CGContextStrokePath(c);
}
```

However, I noticed that I forgot to make the background clear so that it wouldn't block the background of the view. But as soon as I set the background color upon initialization, the drawRect method now resets the context every time drawRect is called.

```
DrawView* draw = [[DrawView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[draw setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
```

I want to **append** the strokes to the context each time drawRect is called, not clear it and then draw, but I also need the background color of the view to be clear.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So why not use `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor([UIColor clearColor].CGColor)`?

Comment: @ChrisH All that does is set the color that it would use if I called a method to draw a filled-in shape on the screen, right? Like `CGContextFillRect()`. Anyways, I just tried that and it made no difference. The background is just the default solid black.

Comment: `drawRect:` must redraw everything. It is not designed to simply add one new line each time. Your code doesn't work properly because it is not drawing all lines each time.

Comment: @rmaddy Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for then? To append the lines, or will I simply need to store all of the line data and redraw it every time?

Comment: Yes, you need to store each line. You should do that anyway for lots of reasons. Then you can do things like undo, scale, rotate, etc.

Comment: @rmaddy So should I store the data in an NSMutableArray? Or is there a more efficient way to do this? I'll be drawing multiple lines at 60 fps.

Comment: An array should work. FYI - there is a much easier way to set the stroke color. Just do: `[self.lineColor setStroke];`. No need to get the `CGColor` or call `CGContextSetStrokeColor`.

Comment: @rmaddy Well thank you sir! Always nice to learn better ways to do things :) If you feel like typing that out in an answer, you definitely answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize my comments into an answer:

`drawRect:` must redraw everything. It is not designed to simply add one new line each time. Your code doesn't work properly because it is not drawing all lines each time.

You will need to keep track of each line in an array or some other appropriate data structure. Then your `drawRect:` method should draw each line each time it is called.

This will allow the background color to work as expected.

This also has the advantage that you can do more with your array of lines. You can provide undo/redo support, scale, rotate, etc.

Another option would be to use `UIBezierPath` instead of keeping an array of lines. You can update the path and render it in your `drawRect:` method.

And the following lines:

```
CGColorRef r = [self.lineColor CGColor];
CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, CGColorGetComponents(r));
```

can be replaced with:

```
[self.lineColor setStroke];
```

Comment: @David I updated the answer to include mention of using `UIBezierPath`. It's probably more efficient than an array of lines.

Comment: Yet another option would be to create your own `CGBitmapContext` as a property, do your drawing into that, and then draw it into your view in `drawRect`. Depending on how complex your `-drawRect` becomes, this could be a more performant option.